# Convert an SVG to a PNG image is missing the fill image pattern

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I am trying to convert an SVG to a PNG image. For this reason I use the npm package "dom-to-image". This and all other packages I tried (e.g. html2canvas) do not show a pattern/image in the polygon.

Here is a small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h5e3aw?file=src/app/app.component.html
(External and internal Images produce the same result.)

How can I convert my complete SVG to a PNG?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should be able to 1. draw SVG to canvas 2. save canvas as PNG

Comment: Yes I am. I have done that. The problem is a picture as a pattern. (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#PatternElement, https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement)

Comment: Are you saying the SVG is not drawn correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your image link to a data URL and it will work.

```
href="data:image/png;base64,iVBO ...snip... gg=="
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yw47xd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, I used an SVG graphic in a <symbol> to bypass the conversion.